# SQL to find duplicate subscribers with the same email address

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, sql, subscriber-key

My company is very soon transitioning to the use of a proprietary subscriber key - we currently use the email address as a subscriber key. I have to do some preliminary investigation into how many people will be affected by this and start reconciling any duplicate accounts.

I would like to see a list of any email addresses that appear more than once, and what their subscriber key is. For example, I am in there several times as a test account, e.g. the following:

```
SubscriberKey     EmailAddress
xyz                x@yz.com
abc                x@yz.com
zyx                x@yz.com
```

It's easy to find these - I just used

```
SELECT SubscriberKey, EmailAddress
FROM _Subscribers
WHERE EmailAddress = 'x@yz.com'
```

And it shows me all the different Subscribers with this email address.
However, I want a list of all Subscriber Keys with multiple email addresses. I tried this:

```
SELECT [SubscriberKey], COUNT([EmailAddress]) AS EmailAddress
FROM _Subscribers
GROUP BY [EmailAddress], [SubscriberKey], 
HAVING COUNT([EmailAddress]) > 1
```

And a couple of variations, but for some reason it returns nothing. Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to try something like that:

> SELECT SubscriberKey, count(EmailAddress)
>   FROM _Subscribers
>   GROUP BY SubscriberKey
>   HAVING count(EmailAddress) > 1

Just for example, I tried with the following Query and it's worked:

> SELECT Name, count(Email)
>   FROM Contact
>   Group By Name
>   HAVING count(Email) > 1

Also, if anything of this doesn't work, you can try to:
1) Make a report with them.
2) Export with DataLoader and put some filters in the newly exported file.

Answer (score 0):

The above query will cause column name error as we need to provide the column names of the data extension. I slightly updated it to the following working version:

SELECT s.SubscriberKey as "SubscriberKey",count(EmailAddress) as "EmailAddress"
FROM [_Subscribers] s GROUP BY SubscriberKey HAVING count(EmailAddress) > 1

Answer (score 0):

This should work (I tested it and it worked for me):

SELECT [SubscriberKey], [EmailAddress]
FROM _Subscribers s
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT [EmailAddress]
FROM _Subscribers ss
WHERE ss.[EmailAddress] = s.[EmailAddress]
GROUP BY [EmailAddress]
HAVING COUNT([EmailAddress]) > 1)